# Unable to loop through an array in angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to iterate an array of objects inside typescript but getting error :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

Below is my code:

```
export class Data{
    products: Product[];

constructor( 
        private route: ActivatedRoute, 
        private router: Router,
        private _http:HttpClient){
            this.getProducts().subscribe(products=> this.products= products);

        } 


    ngOnInit(){
        let productId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
        this.id= productId;
        this.getProducts();
        this.findProduct();
    }

    findProduct(){
      this.products.forEach((product,index) =>{
          console.log(product.name);
          console.log(index);
      })
    }

    getProducts(){
        return this._http.get<Product[]>('../src/assets/product-data.json');
    }
```

I have tried many solutions but none worked.
I have imported `BrowserModule` and `CommonModule` inside my module.
Is there anyway I can resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the world of asynchronous execution.

When you execute your `findProduct()` method, the HTTP request that retrieves the product information has not yet returned, so your `products` array is not yet defined/initialized.

To fix, add the call to `findProduct()` to the observer for `getProducts()`:

```
this.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
  this.products = products;
  this.findProduct();
});
```

Probably also cleaner to put that logic in your `ngOnInit()` method instead of your constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robby.  :)

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the observable hasn't been completed by the time you try to iterate over the array. As such, the array is still undefined.

Try setting the products to [ ] in the constructor and then subscribe to the observable in ngOnInit. This should at the very least prevent an undefined error.